# How to create an F# struct with a function member and a default public constructor?

Tags: struct, constructor, f#

I need to create a `struct` type for passing to an external class that is not under my control.  That class requires that my `struct` type has a public default constructor.  I need it to have a function type as a member.

The following produces `error FS0001: A generic construct requires that the type 'MyStruct' have a public default constructor`:

```
[<Struct>]
type MyStruct =
    val callBack: unit -> unit
    new(cb: unit -> unit) = { callBack = cb }

type ExternalClass<'T when 'T : (new : unit -> 'T) and 'T : struct> () =
    member val something = new 'T()

let c = new ExternalClass<MyStruct>()
```

This works fine if the type of the member is changed from `unit -> unit` to `int`.

I've tried using a `DefaultValue` attribute, which according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/explicit-fields-the-val-keyword) should work fine on a function member, but this produces two errors: `error FS0765: Extraneous fields have been given values` and `error FS0696: This is not a valid object construction expression. Explicit object constructors must either call an alternate constructor or initialize all fields of the object and specify a call to a super class constructor.`

How can I create a suitable type to meet the external class's constraint?

Comment: I'm not at all sure I understand the problem in depth, but can the CLIMutable attribute help? That's what I used in the past to have default constructors generated so that some C# libraries would accept certain types. Are you sure it's a struct you need?

Comment: @BentTranberg Yes, it has to be a struct - the external class requires this.  I've added this constraint to the sample code.

Comment: @BentTranberg The `CLIMutable` attribute appears to only apply to F# record types, so can't be used here.

Comment: @MarkPattison , you can use record syntax & `StructAttribute`: `[<Struct; CLIMutable>] type MyStruct = { Callback : unit -> unit }`

Comment: @JL0PD such type won't have a default constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the type `unit -> unit` does not have a default value. Here's a shorter repro:

```
[<Struct>]
type MyStruct =
    val callBack: unit -> unit

let s = MyStruct()
```

You get an error on the last line saying: `The default, zero-initializing constructor of a struct type may only be used if all the fields of the struct type admit default initialization`

The type `unit -> unit` doesn't admit default initialization. It must have a value of function type, and there is no such thing as "default" function value.

This is how structs in .NET work: every struct always has a default constructor, and the programmer doesn't get to implement it. Instead, the runtime initializes all fields with their default values. The idea behind this is to make allocating arrays or structs very cheap: you just zero out a memory block, and voila!

So by this logic, your `callBack` field must be zero-outable, but it can't be, because in F# function-typed variables can't be `null`.

It works fine with `int`, because `int` does indeed have a default value of zero.

---

Now, a "good" solution would depend on what it is you're actually trying to do. But in the absence of that information, I can suggest a couple of local workarounds.

**First option** - make the field have type `obj` (so its default value would be `null`) and provide a safe-ish accessor that would return an `option`:

```
[<Struct>]
type MyStruct =
    val private callBack: obj
    member this.Callback with get() = this.callBack |> Option.ofObj |> Option.map (fun o -> o :?> (unit -> unit))
    new(cb: unit -> unit) = { callBack = cb }
```

The `Callback` accessor property would then return a `(unit -> unit) option`, which would be `Some` if the function was initialized or `None` if it wasn't:

```
> MyStruct().Callback;;
val it : (unit -> unit) option = None

> MyStruct(fun() -> ()).Callback;;
val it : (unit -> unit) option = Some <fun:it@10>
```

---

**Second option** - wrap the callback in a nullable type:

```
[<AllowNullLiteral>] 
type ACallback(cb : unit -> unit) = 
    member val Callback = cb with get

[<Struct>]
type MyStruct =
    val callBack: ACallback
    new(cb: unit -> unit) = { callBack = ACallback cb }
```

Then:

```
> MyStruct().callBack;;
val it : ACallback = <null>

> MyStruct(fun() -> ()).callBack;;
val it : ACallback = FSI_0006+ACallback {Callback = <fun:it@30-1>;}
```

This (arguably) provides a bit more type safety at the expense of an extra allocation.

Plus, there is a possibility of getting a `null`, but if that's a problem, you can wrap that in an `option`-typed accessor too:

```
[<Struct>]
type MyStruct =
    val private callBack: ACallback
    member this.Callback with get() = this.callBack |> Option.ofObj |> Option.map (fun c -> c.Callback)
    new(cb: unit -> unit) = { callBack = ACallback cb }

> MyStruct().Callback;;
val it : (unit -> unit) option = None

> MyStruct(fun() -> ()).Callback;;
val it : (unit -> unit) option = Some <fun:it@38-2>
```

Comment: In fact, for a callback, method 1 is even cleaner - I can just match on `callback` and either invoke it or return `()`.